# Exit-pop Javascript setup on WP site with CF7 on particular events

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I got some buttons on a website "www.domain.com":

1. some a href plain text links like "Click Here to request Callback"
2. some img wrapped in a hrefs to pop-up a Contact Form 7 forms
3. Contact Form 7 forms with Submit buttons

and I got an Exit-pop script which works if user clicks X button to close the window. This script just asks something like "Are you sure? We got and special offer and click CANCEL" and than he is redirected to special offer page "www.domain.com/sale/".

But problem is if user Orders something 3) he is still got special discount offer! And the logic is - if he click a button 1) or 2) (callback or just button to popup CF7 form but not Submited an order in CF7) it is OK to run a JavaScript for him, and if he entered his phone in CF7 Order form and successfully Submitted it ("on_sent_ok" event for example mb?) he is done and no need to give him an discount offer JavaScript. And of course somehow it should detect that if user on "www.domain.com/sale/" page the script should don’t fire up to prevent double offering.

I got this script on some forum, but:
First it doesn't fun after 1) and 2) buttons hit (even if a user hit "Order" but that he didn't submitted it and just leave the site). And second it is still fires on "www.domain.com/sale/" page.

The script:

```
<script language="javascript">
(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
var __redirect_to = 'http://domain.com/sale/';

var _tags = ['button', 'input', 'a'], _els, _i, _i2;
for(_i in _tags) {
    _els = document.getElementsByTagName(_tags[_i]);
    for(_i2 in _els) {
        if((_tags[_i] == 'input' && _els[_i2].type != 'button' && _els[_i2].type != 'submit' && _els[_i2].type != 'image') || _els[_i2].target == '_blank') continue;
        _els[_i2].onclick = function() {window.onbeforeunload = function(){};}
    }
}

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {};
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.location.href = __redirect_to;
        }, 500);
    },5);
    return 'WAIT BEFORE YOU GO! CLICK THE *CANCEL* BUTTON RIGHT NOW! PAGE. I HAVE SOMETHING VERY SPECIAL FOR YOU COMPLETELY FREE.';
}
}, 500);
})();
</script>
```